# Wordpress menu that shows all posts in a certain category like w3schools

Tags: posts, categories, menus, sidebar

I am working on creating a widget menu(kind of a sidebar like w3schools) that is supposed to show all posts that are listed in a particular category. And update automatically from particular category(Ex:- HTML).
[image: [w3schools image]]

Comment: Please ask a question.

Comment: What is your actual question? Can you provide some code?